# How to get the type of value?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

The value is in a xs:map，and perhaps different type, such as: 'xs:string',  'xs:integer', 'xs:sequence' , even another 'xs:map', and so on. How to judge his type?

Comment: Due to hierachic type system, there is no single specific type a value or variable has, if you have e.g. `<xsl:variable name="s1" select="'foo'"/>` then `$s1 instance of xs:string` is true, but `$s1 instance of item()` and `$s1 instance of xs:string?` as well, so you can't determine "the" type, you can check with `instance of` for a certain type match.As for maps, they are also items in general and they are also functions, so again `instance of item()` would be true, as various map sequence types.

Comment: Cmf: Was the func-type useful?

Answer (score 3):

You can test the type of a value using the `instance of` operator, for example `$x instance of map(xs:string, node()*)`.

You cannot ask "what is the type of this value", because (a) there is no way of returning the answer (types are not values and therefore cannot be returned as the result of an expression), and (b) there is no unique answer: a given map will be an instance of many different types.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the FXSL library for XSLT 2.0 offers for determining the type of an item:

https://github.com/dnovatchev/FXSL-XSLT2/blob/master/f/func-type.xsl

Here is the code, but do note that a few more FXSL files are being exported

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/04/xpath-datatypes"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f xs xdt"
 >
  <xsl:import href="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="kConstructor" match="*" use="@t"/>

  <xsl:variable name="f:vTypeConstructors">
    <f:unsignedByte t="xs:unsignedByte"/>
    <f:unsignedShort t="xs:unsignedShort"/>
    <f:unsignedInt t="xs:unsignedInt"/>
    <f:unsignedLong t="xs:unsignedLong"/>
    <f:positiveInteger t="xs:positiveInteger"/>
    <f:nonNegativeInteger t="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    <f:nonPositiveInteger t="xs:nonPositiveInteger"/>
    <f:byte t="xs:byte"/>
    <f:short t="xs:short"/>
    <f:int t="xs:int"/>
    <f:long t="xs:long"/>
    <f:integer t="xs:integer"/>
    <f:decimal t="xs:decimal"/>
    <f:double t="xs:double"/>
    <f:float t="xs:float"/>
    <f:NMTOKEN t="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
    <f:NMTOKENS t="xs:NMTOKENS"/>
    <f:ENTITIES t="xs:ENTITIES"/>
    <f:ENTITY t="xs:ENTITY"/>
    <f:IDREF t="xs:IDREF"/>
    <f:IDREFS t="xs:IDREFS"/>
    <f:ID t="xs:ID"/>
    <f:NCName t="xs:NCName"/>
    <f:Name t="xs:Name"/>
    <f:language t="xs:language"/>
    <f:token t="xs:token"/>
    <f:normalizedString t="xs:normalizedString"/>
    <f:boolean t="xs:boolean"/>
    <f:duration t="xs:duration"/>
    <f:dateTime t="xs:dateTime"/>
    <f:time t="xs:time"/>
    <f:date t="xs:date"/>
    <f:gYearMonth t="xs:gYearMonth"/>
    <f:gYear t="xs:gYear"/>
    <f:gMonthDay t="xs:gMonthDay"/>
    <f:gDay t="xs:gDay"/>
    <f:gMonth t="xs:gMonth"/>
    <f:base64Binary t="xs:base64Binary"/>
    <f:hexBinary t="xs:hexBinary"/>
    <f:anyURI t="xs:anyURI"/>
    <f:QName t="xs:QName"/>
    <f:NOTATION t="xs:NOTATION"/>
    <f:string t="xs:string"/>
    <f:yearMonthDuration t="xdt:yearMonthDuration"/>
    <f:dayTimeDuration t="xdt:dayTimeDuration"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:function name="f:Constructor" as="element()">
    <xsl:param name="pTypename" as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:sequence select="key('kConstructor', $pTypename,$f:vTypeConstructors)"/>  
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="f:typeConstructor" as="element()">
    <xsl:param name="pThis"/>

    <xsl:sequence select="key('kConstructor', f:type($pThis),$f:vTypeConstructors)"/>  
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="f:type" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="pThis"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:decimal">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'"  test="true()">
                <xsl:choose>
<!--       Not supported by a Basic XSLT Processor -->        
                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:unsignedByte">xs:unsignedByte</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:unsignedShort">xs:unsignedShort</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:unsignedInt">xs:unsignedInt</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:unsignedLong">xs:unsignedLong</xsl:when>

                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:positiveInteger">xs:positiveInteger</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:nonNegativeInteger">xs:nonNegativeInteger</xsl:when>

                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:negativeInteger">xs:negativeInteger</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:nonPositiveInteger">xs:nonPositiveInteger</xsl:when>

                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:byte">xs:byte</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:short">xs:short</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:int">xs:int</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:long">xs:long</xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
<!--      End of SA only types  -->
                    </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:integer">xs:integer</xsl:when>

          <xsl:otherwise>xs:decimal</xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:double">xs:double</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:float">xs:float</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:string">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'"  test="true()">
<!--       Not supported by a Basic XSLT Processor -->        
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:NMTOKEN">xs:NMTOKEN</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:ENTITY">xs:ENTITY</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:IDREF">xs:IDREF</xsl:when>

              <!-- TODO: What to do with list simple types?
              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:NMTOKEN+">xs:NMTOKENS</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:ENTITY+">xs:ENTITIES</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:IDREF+">xs:IDREFS</xsl:when> 
              -->

              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:ID">xs:ID</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:NCName">xs:NCName</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:Name">xs:Name</xsl:when>

              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:language">xs:language</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:token">xs:token</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:normalizedString">xs:normalizedString</xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>xs:string</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:when> 
          <xsl:when test="true()">xs:string</xsl:when> 
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:boolean">xs:boolean</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:duration">xs:duration</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:dateTime">xs:dateTime</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:time">xs:time</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:date">xs:date</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:gYearMonth">xs:gYearMonth</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:gYear">xs:gYear</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:gMonthDay">xs:gMonthDay</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:gDay">xs:gDay</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:gMonth">xs:gMonth</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xdt:yearMonthDuration">xdt:yearMonthDuration</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xdt:dayTimeDuration">xdt:dayTimeDuration</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:base64Binary">xs:base64Binary</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:hexBinary">xs:hexBinary</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:anyURI">xs:anyURI</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xs:QName">xs:QName</xsl:when>

      <xsl:when use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'"
           test="$pThis instance of xs:NOTATION">xs:NOTATION</xsl:when>

<!--
      <xsl:when test="$pThis instance of xdt:untypedAtomic">xdt:untypedAtomic</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>Unknown xdt:untypedAtomic</xsl:otherwise>
-->
      <xsl:when test="$pThis[1] instance of node()">xml:node</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>xs:string</xsl:otherwise>      
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**And here is a test of this FXSL function:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f xs"
 >
  <xsl:import href="../f/func-type.xsl"/>

  <!-- To be applied on ../data/numList.xml -->

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03'): <xsl:value-of select="f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03')"/>
    f:apply(f:typeConstructor('xxx'),'03'): <xsl:value-of select="f:apply(f:typeConstructor('xxx'),'03')"/>
    f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03') gt 4: <xsl:value-of select="f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03') gt 4"/>
    f:type(f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03')): <xsl:value-of select="f:type(f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03'))"/>
    f:type(f:apply(f:typeConstructor('string'), 3)): <xsl:value-of select="f:type(f:apply(f:typeConstructor('string'),'03'))"/>
<!--  Supported only by a SA Processor -->
    xs:token('abc') : <xsl:value-of  select="f:type(xs:token('abc'))"
       use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'"/>

    -1 : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(-1)"/>
<!--  Supported only by a SA Processor -->
    xs:negativeInteger(-1) : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(xs:negativeInteger(-1))"
       use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'" />
    xs:nonPositiveInteger(0) : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(xs:nonPositiveInteger(0))"
       use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'" />

    0 : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(0)"/>
    3 : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(3)"/>
    3. : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(3.)"/>
    3.0E1 : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(3.0E1)"/>
    xs:float(3) : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(xs:float(3))"/>
<!--  Supported only by a SA Processor -->
    xs:positiveInteger(3) : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(xs:positiveInteger(3))"
       use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'" />

   '3' : <xsl:value-of select="f:type('3')"/>
   (/*/*/text())[1] : <xsl:value-of select="f:type((/*/*/text())[1])"/>
   data((/*/*/text())[1]) : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(data((/*/*/text())[1]))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**All supported types are deduced and output**.

Do note:

1. This code has commented out fragments for some of the XML Schema types, which are only recognized by a schema-aware XSLT processor. In case you have a SA processor, feel free to uncomment the code and then in the result of the transformation these types (which now produce the empty string) should also appear.
2. The code can be updated to also deduce the types that were introduced in XPath 3, such as *map*, *function* and *array*

Comment: Is the namespace `xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/04/xpath-datatypes"` part of an earlier XPath 2.0 draft? It seems in the XPath 2 standard https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-predefined-types the schema namespace/prefix `xs` is used for all types like `xs:anyAtomicType`. It might also be worth pointing out that in XSLT 3/XPath 3 most of the restrictions on primitive types that XSLT/XPath 2 made for basic processors are removed.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Good notice! The above code is from 2006. When I find time I will update it accordingly. Will also add detection of array, map and function